# Why can't NPM modules be entirely flat including dependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm, architecture, dependencies, dependency-management

So as far as I understand NPM you may have a dependency structure like

```
        APP
  /      |      \
A1.0    B1.0    C3.0
  |    /    \    |   \
C1.5 D1.27 C1.5 D1.27 A1.0
```

The reason it can't be entirely flat is because there can be many different versions of module C

But why can't we just rename the folders to their versions and have a completely flat structure, and use symbolic links ?

```
          APP
  /   /    |    \   \
A1.0 B1.0 C1.5 C3.0 D1.27
 ^|   |---^^|----^|--^-^
 ||-------| |----||--|
 |----------|
```

As I understand it. NPM3 / Microsoft RUSH / PNPM will try to flatten things, but still keep a sub dependency structure

```
        APP
  /   /    \   \
A1.0 B1.0 C3.0 D1.27
  |   |
C1.5 C1.5
```

Here since there is already module C, it throws the other version of C into a sub dependency of A.  But now we'd have two C1.5's

Am I missing something ?
Is there a manager that does true flattening and sym links ?
Is there a reason why a flat structure will not work ?

Thank you

Comment: *Here since there is already module C, it throws the other version of C into a sub dependency of A. But now we'd have two C1.5's* - what's your case? NPM usually doesn't do that. Even if it does by accident, there's `npm dedupe`. It's impractical or impossible for a hierarchy to be entirely flat because packages aren't necessarily unambiguously identified by their versions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had this issue too, but it's happens rarely, in most cases I have flat structure of dependencies.
I am not sure  if it's your case, but maybe it happens when module A depends on module C and module C depends on A.